# Ant design charts install error: '__spreadArray' is not exported from 'tslib'

Tags: node.js, antd

I tried to install ant design charts but I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/@antv/algorithm/es/gaddi.js
Attempted import error: '__spreadArray' is not exported from 'tslib'.
```

I get 0 warnings. the steps I have done:

1. `npm install @ant-design/charts`
2. `npm install tslib --save`
3. `npm audit fix`
4. `npm react update`
5. `npm i typescript`

I tried like 3 times reinstalling these, but none of them solved my problems. Any idea what's wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently by installing the latest tslib package worked for me:

```
npm install tslib@latest --save
```

Comment: I have been trying to solve this on and off all evening. Thank you, manually applying the @latest version resolved it for me (basic example react app but adding chakra-ui).  In my case I ran `yarn upgrade tslib@latest` and bam, it compiled and ran smoothly. THANKS!

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting this, saved me god-only-knows-how-much time!